# Unable to install Snap7 Library on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, scada

I'm new to Linux based OS's (and very new to Snap7).
Trying to install Snap7 library on Ubuntu machine following instructions at - http://python-snap7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html. However I'm getting the following errors during the 3rd step

```
E: Unable to locate package libsnap71
E: Unable to locate package libsnap7-dev
```

I'm not sure how exactly to manually install it and I'm unsure how to fix this installation issue so any advice whould be fantastic :)

Below is a copy of the log after already running the "add repository" command:

```
administrator@*pc-name*:~/Documents/*folder*$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]   
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Get:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [299 kB]
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Get:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [184 kB]
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial Release           
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 673 kB in 13s (50.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/snap7/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
administrator@*pc-name*:~/Documents/*folder*$ sudo apt-get install libsnap71 libsnap7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsnap71
E: Unable to locate package libsnap7-dev
```

Please let me know if you need more information to make a proper assessment.

Comment: Isn't problem with it thats You are using **Xenial** Ubuntu (logs says it) and your package manager tries to obtain this version on snap ? 
As I can see at repo there are versions **vidy, trusty and precise**. So maybe You should to try install specific version ? Maybe this for **vivid**
At repo page there is short manual hot to do this :
https://launchpad.net/~gijzelaar/+archive/ubuntu/snap7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed this part on the very page you linked to:

```
If you are using Ubuntu you can use the Ubuntu packages from our launchpad PPA.
To install:

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/snap7
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libsnap71 libsnap7-dev
```

Execute all three commands in order and you should be fine. *However*, as the software is older than your system, you need to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.d` file created after the first step and replace `xenial` (or even `yaketty`) with `trusty`.  The ppa only has builds for older releases.

Comment: You also missed his 
   "However I'm getting the following errors during the 3rd step" 
:)

Comment: I didn't. That's why I suggested to modify the `sources.list` created by `add-apt-repository` as it will **not** correspond to his default (current) distro.  The docs for `snap7` installation are simply stale.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Dirk! I did run the first step with add repository (just didn't paste above sorry). I've found the directory you mentioned (was named "sources.list.d") and can see 2 xenial.list files in there, how do I replace them with trusty? Do I make copies of the current list files and modify the contents to trusty?

Comment: Edit within to replace `xenial` with `trusty`. Or download the snap7 files by hand and install via `dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 0):

This works well right now, use instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Egijzelaar/+archive/ubuntu/snap7)

```
 $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/snap7
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install libsnap7-dev libsnap7-1
```